# Writing massive dictionary to file in python

Tags: python, json

I'm writing a huge dictionary to disk - its handled in memory just fine, but when I output it, I get an error related to the fact that the json written is not complete. How can I write out or stream out a massive dictionary?

I'm using the following:

```
jsontext = json.dumps(data_dict)
f = open(pre_data_file, 'w')
f.write(jsontext)
f.close()
```

and

```
f = open(predump_file, 'r')
jsontxt = f.read()
f.close()
sample_dict = dict(json.loads(jsontxt))
```

My file size (incomplete) is: ~300M

Here is the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Combine.py", line 675, in <module>
    sample_range = dict( json.loads(jsontxt))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

when performing a tail on the file (waiting a while as its one line)...

Comment: can you post the traceback?

Comment: I woudn't call 300 M massive. but yes, some traceback would be useful.

Comment: do you get more mileage out of `f = open(...); json.dump(data_dict,f); f.close()` ?

Comment: kindly state a few details about the problem:  `data_dict.__sizeof__` + `len( data_dict.keys() )`

Comment: The code your stack trace points to is not the code you've posted.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson whoops. Asleep at the wheel...I'll go and check now.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer was posted before OP was edit-ed to include the `json.loads()` code, the root cause of the `dict` constructor exception reported*

---

### Format overhead

Python `dict` has it's own in-memory representation footprint ( format overhead ) by far bigger, than that of the flat, serialised, JSON format.

`JSON` format wrapper on `json.dump()` adds itself a minimum overhead to a properly formatted `dict`.

**However** the `json.dumps()` variant stores the full-length monolythic output string again into your memory.

### Memory-footprint requirements

If your in-memory situation does not allow, try another processing strategy, so as the output is generated sequentially and goes rather in a pipeline with a direct output to file as `json.dump()` provides tools for, or -- in case of having a complex `dict` structure -- create your own `dict` slicing-iterator, that removes one level of dict structure and allows `json.dump()` to traverse sequentially over all `.keys()`, processing just the remaining depth of the `dict[key]` leaves -- principally almost like this trivial iterator `[ for aKey in data_dict: f.write( json.dump( aKey ) + ":" ), f.write( data_dict[aKey] ), ... ]`

All this done not to double the in-memory allocation needs ( your code effectively puts a full-scale textual replica of the `data_dict` into a string variable `jsontext` and your O/S will have to handle massive memory swaps in case your `data_dict` sizes grow to ranges you call massive )

Check you actual `data_dict` situation and estimated memory needs with

`data_dict.__sizeof__()`

and

`len( data_dict.keys() )`

Comment: Very informative answer but the error he's getting is related to the usage of the `dict` constructor with the json-loaded data.

Comment: Right, aneroid. Thanks for your compliments. Also you may notice, that *json-load* part of code-sample was posted as an edit, after the answer was posted. At the time the answer was created, there were just 4-SLOC-s on `.dumps()`/`f.write()`

Comment: Oh, I didn't read the edits. +1 anyway coz I'm doing stuff with objects derived by parsing JSON data, which is anywhere between 300 KB to 1 MB per instance, and one of these derived objects occurs 50 to 100 times from each piece of JSON data. Fortunately, I was memory-usage conscious from the beginning so haven't seen crazy RAM spikes when I execute. Used `slots` and added code to be able to serialize and un-serialize.

Comment: NP, I work with BLOBs, where both RAM & time ( & non-blocking IO & GC ) matter :o)

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is related to the usage of the `dict` constructor with the already-json-loaded data.

When you do:

```
sample_dict = dict(json.loads(jsontxt))
```

...you're creating a dict from a python object - dict, list, etc. which has already been loaded. So basically that object has to be valid to pass as a parameter to the `dict()` constructor. That's the equivalent of:

```
d1 = dict({'a': 1})  # works
d2 = dict(['a', 1])  # doesn't work and gives the
                     # error you got
d3 = dict(('a', 1))  # nope, same error
```

Since you are already loading the string from the file with `loads()`, you can just do:

```
sample_dict = json.loads(jsontxt)
```

Which is the opposite of how you `dumps()`ed it in the beginning.

Btw, [`dump()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) and [`load()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) work with files directly, instead of using a string in between to write and read the data to/from the file.